Some Material icons are not rendering in my Angular project
In my Angular project, some Material icons don't seem to be rendering:
<mat-icon>domino_mask</mat-icon>
<mat-icon>hourglass</mat-icon>

The other icons render normally. I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Cleaned the node_modules directory and re-ran npm install.
Updated Angular Material using ng update
Verified that MatIconModule is imported in my module.
Checked that the  tag for Material Icons is present in my index.html:

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Any advice on what might be going wrong or additional steps I could try would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Both domino_mask and hourglass icons are from the Material Symbols Outlined stylesheet.
Covered in this answer, you need to:

Import the Material Symbols Outlined stylesheet in the index.html.

<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined"
/>


Specify the fontSet attribute to both <mat-icon> elements.

<mat-icon fontSet="material-symbols-outlined">domino_mask</mat-icon>
<mat-icon fontSet="material-symbols-outlined">hourglass</mat-icon>

Demo @ StackBlitz

thanks it works, i already had the outlined stylesheet but i did not have the attribute fontSet,
